# .htaccess issues with subfolders

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having some trouble with my .htaccess. First, I've created a subfolder and then I've made that subfolder as root like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

So far so good, problem is when I request something like:

> mysite.com/subfolder/page

Or hit refresh it takes me to the main domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have this code in `app/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: trully grateful for your reply man, but it didn't work, that will redirect the website to my subfolder, i want the root to work normally, just need to be able to refresh on the subfolder

Comment: oh and when i refresh the page, this will show 

"Not Found

The requested document was not found on this server.
Web Server at domain.co.uk"

Comment: Can you clarify with example URLs what you mean by `i want the root to work normally, just need to be able to refresh on the subfolder`?

Comment: sure can bruv, https://www.escortsapp.co.uk, is working fine, https://www.escortsapp.co.uk/app thats the subfolder im having the issue

Comment: But you must understand that 2 statements i.e. `i want the root to work normally` and earlier `i've made that subfolder as root` are opposite of each other.

Comment: oh i get it, im sorry, is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: I need clarification from you on this. I suggest you make up your mind and clarify with examples in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127547/discussion-between-bruno-simoes-and-anubhava).